# Saving file with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

I have an excel template stored at some specified location like my Desktop and I want to save that file through VBA as per list of names which are in column B (B2:B100) of another workbook. So, to shorten this I want my Workbook1 to be stored at some specified location as per list of names stored in Workbook2 through VBA.

I tried to execute some code but it was saving the file in which the code was written instead of the file I want. I'm a complete novice in VBA. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please include the code (as text) that you have tried so far, identify what does not work about it, including any error text and number (and on which line if an error). Perhaps check out the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Comment: So you are storing in the excel file the paths to where the file should be saved?